# Properly defining functions after they have been used in expressions

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am having trouble with how functions behave when defined, after they have been used in an expression. More specifically, I start with an expression of the form:

`f = f11[r] + f11'[r] + f22[r] + f22'[r]`

and want to define the explicit form of `f11/f22` afterwards. If I define the functions `f11[r_] = r^2 + r; f22[r_] = b r` and then simplify `f`, the code behaves as expected. However, I want to define `f11/f22` as some coefficient of another already defined expression. E.g. `C = (r^2 + r) x1 + (b r) x2` and `f11[r] = Coefficient[C, x1], f22[r] = Coefficient[C, x2]`. The second example does not work as expected and I cannot figure out why. Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: btw, you should really use `:=` to define function as a rule of thumb. There are cases where `=`  is used, but that is the exception to the rule. As for your main question, may be it is related to this or may be not. Did not look at it yet all.

Comment: I have to make assumptions about your actual code, for your question to make sense. `f11/f22` shouldn't change in either case, but remain `f11/f22`.  There are no arguments to `f11` or `f22`. Also in the first example you defined your functions with a pattern `r_` and in the second with a literal `r`. `C` is a protected system symbol. These are different. I cannot know what exact code you tried that did not work as expected. If it was `C =...` it's because `C` is `Protected`.

Comment: Ref: [Avoid starting your variables with a capital.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999)

Comment: Turns out I have to use ```:=``` , in order for the function to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
f11 = Function[r,r^2 + r]; f22 = Function[r, b r];
```

If you want to extract the approporiate expressions for functions from other expressions, e.g., from

```
C1 = (r^2 + r) x1 + (b r) x2;
```

you should take care of evaluation of the second argument of `Function` e.g., with

```
f11 = Function[r,#]&[Coefficient[C1, x1]];
```

or

```
f11 = Function[r,Evaluate[Coefficient[C1, x1]]];
```

Note that it might be more safe to apply the corresponding rules to the required expressions, like that:

```
f/.{f11 -> Function[r,Evaluate[Coefficient[C1, x1]]], f22 -> Function[r,Evaluate[Coefficient[C1, x2]]]}
```

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, the problem is the following: If I do not explicitly tell Mathematica to evaluate the `Coefficient[]`, everywhere where the specific function is called, the coefficient will be called explicitly, assuming that C1 can change, while otherwise it will only be called once when the function is created?